# maintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" does not work globally after setting in web.config ,but works in page level,what should I do?

Tags: asp.net, web-config, iis-6, windows-server-2003

setting **maintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true"**  globally in web.config **does work** in my xp sp3 under iis 5.1 but not for production server(win server 2003 sp2 with .NET 3.5 sp1 and IIS 6).
but if add **MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true"** for any  <%@ Page directive it is working like a champ.

I don't know if I should  add clear tag for web.config to override it in IIS 6 or something?

 Any Advice,tips or comments would be Appreciated

here is the related section in web.config

```
<pages maintainScrollPositionOnPostBack="true" validateRequest="false" enableEventValidation="false" viewStateEncryptionMode="Never" enableViewStateMac="false" >
  <controls>
     ....       
  </controls>
</pages>
```

--------update---------

I don't know what was the real problem then when i post the question ,right now i have no problem with maintainScrollPositionOnPostback=“true” in my new system with windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

might be a problem with case sensitivity - try `maintainScrollPositionOnPostback` (lowercase `m`)

Comment: there is still a typo in the main question - it should start with upper-case M for the Page directive: <%@ Page MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" />

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem. But after inspecting markup found out problem was with one of the update panel. Check update panels if you have similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hey i found solution on [Javascript file](http://en.hasheminezhad.com/scrollsaver)

Just add in your header file after jquery library

I think this will resolve your problem its works perfect for me.

Comment: Page is no longer available. This is why you should share the code in StackOverflow instead of posting links.