# gridview with many pages returned not maintaining scroll position

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have an issue with maintaining scroll position.

I am almost positive that I have everything set correctly. I have updated my web config...

```
<pages maintainScrollPositionOnPostBack="true"
```

and everything seems to work fine UNTIL....

When  ever my Gridview returns a lot of pages, like more than 50, sometimes upwards of 100 or more, I show 50 records per page. The farther into the Gridview, the more the scroll position is off.

So what I am saying is that for the first 20 plus pages or so, if I scroll down the page to the point where the top rows have moved off the screen and I enter Edit Mode, the correct record remains in view on Postback.

But if I am over say around 30 pages into the Gridview, the further in the worse it gets, when i enter Edit Mode I have to scroll back down to the location of the record that I selected to edit.

Any ideas on this one will be tested, my users are going nutts!!!

thanks again,

Comment: Have you tried putting the grid in Update Panel ?

Comment: And how is that going to fix the display height issue he's experiencing?

Comment: As an added note, it seems that this is a rolling problem. Getting into the 60 to 70 page range the scroll position is starting to maintain again. I can tell that it is moving, but only by a few rows until I get 20 or so pages away from the point. Major bug in my opinion.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a link to an alternative solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap the gridview in a div set with overflow:auto.  Then with js reset the scroll position when the page loads. something like this.

```
<body onload="GetDivPosition()">
<form id="form1" runat="server">

<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnField" runat="server" Value="0" />

<div style="overflow:auto;" ID="gridArea" onscroll="SetDivPosition()">

<asp:GridView ID="yourGrid" runat="server">
      .....
</asp:GridView>

</div>


<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

        function GetDivPosition() {
            var hdn = document.getElementById("hdnField");
            document.getElementById("gridArea").scrollTop = hdn.value;
        }

        function SetDivPosition() {
            var hdn = document.getElementById("hdnField");
            hdn.value = document.getElementById("gridArea").scrollTop;
        }
</script>
```

Visual studio will probably give you warnings that onscroll isn't valid but it has always worked for me.  If your using an update panel it's a little more complicated.  Actually all of mine are in update panels so I tried to revert this code back, so hopefully this will work for you.

Answer (score -1):

The [MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.maintainscrollpositiononpostback.aspx) property only works in IE so unless this is an Intranet situation where everybody is using IE, then this is not a good solution. There are browserCaps hacks for other browsers but not even Microsoft supports this.

If you are using paging, then the simplest option is to reduce the number of records per page. Only other "clean" option remaining would be to roll your own jQuery solution.

Here's an approach without using the MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback property:

http://www.kodergurl.com/2010/08/maintain-scroll-position-on-post-back.html

Comment: The correct syntax according to intellisense is a lower case "m". Note also there are other posts on this site reporting the same issue with problems using upper case "M"

Comment: can you consider using Update Panel ?

Comment: This property is not supported in browsers outside of IE http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866770/maintainscrollpositiononpostback-not-working-with-firefox

Comment: @marc this is obviously a bug; question is what happens his app if they fix it?!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084229/maintainscrollpositiononpostback-true-does-not-work-globally-after-setting-in

Comment: I've removed casing issue from Q.

Comment: @Irish the added solution you offered from kodergurl will not work in my situtation as the site has multiple Master pages so the form tag is not available on the specific aspx page which contains the Gridview. Only one server side form tag can exist.

Comment: I managed to find a fix for the "multiple form tag" issue ;-) http://codersbarn.com/post/2008/03/08/Solution-to-ASPNET-Form-PayPal-Problem.aspx (go to Jeremy's link in my blog post)